# Angular 1.5 component Expression 'undefined' in attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm trying to use AngularJs 1.5 components but everytime I declare `bindings` I keep getting this error:

> Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'message' used with directive 'homeComp' is non-assignable!

I'm trying a simple component, just to learn it, this is the code:

```
var component = {
  bindings: {
      message: '='
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: function MainController() {
    this.message = 'Welcome to my component';

    function debug() {
      this.message = 'This message changed';
    }
    this.debug = debug;
  },
  template: [
    'Message: {{ vm.message }}<br />',
    '<button ng-click="vm.debug()">Change message</button>'
  ].join(``)
};
```

You can see the error here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uutk5kxOVpa5eLfjoa8U?p=preview

What is wrong with the code? Or what is causing this error? If I remove the bindings, the error doesn't appear and I can change the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the `binding` option in your component if the property being referenced is only used by the component itself.

By using `binding` with the `=` for the `message` property, you are specifically telling the directive that the parameter is a two way binding, meaning that it will be set in the **parent** HTML, and that changes to the `message` property should be written back to the HTML.  Because the `<home-comp>` tag does not have a `message` property, the HTML is not assignable (cannot be written back to).

There are three ways to fix this error:

1. Enforce the `<home-comp message="default message">` requirement and always provide the property in the HTML.
2. Define the `binding` to be optional, by using `message: '=?'`. [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cTJHt8EgxvUrjeGHb3xe?p=preview)
3. Remove the `message` property from the `binding` completely, if it is not intended to be set from the HTML.

[More info from the docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=message&p2=homeComp)

Comment: I'm using the bindings because I may have one-way-databind data as well as two-way, depending on the use case. Since I'm starting using components, I tried both, but had this error when using like the example above. So if I have a One-way data binding, how should I do?

Comment: did you specifically try defining `message` as optional, as I show working in the plunkr for the 2nd line item?

Comment: Yes, it worked for a 2 way data-binding, but if I change to `<` it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: well that seems to be a different question, since you don't even mention using `<` in your question body and aren't using it in the example you posted.  I'll experiment with it a bit though and see what might be going on.

Comment: just messing with the plunker, `<` throws an error because there is no matching HTML to read from, but `<?` seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes, but I think I'm understanding how it works! =D Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've defined message as a 2 way binding, but your html doesn't provide anything to bind to.

This line:

```
<home-comp></home-comp>
```

should be

```
<home-comp message='myMessageVariable'></home-comp>
```

And you need to declare myMessageVariable somewhere in the scope.

Comment: But when I declare `this.message = '...'` isn't the same? Could you provide a working example?